# multiple row selection in datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

flex example to select multiple row selection in datagrid

Comment: It's traditional to ask questions on this site

Comment: ... and be specific about what you're trying to find out. Trust me, you'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

set this to the datagrid

```
allowMultipleSelection="true"
```